# Prevention updation of records through trigger

Tags: trigger

I need to prevent creation of new Lead records 
if Lead record name contains 'R' letter in it.

I need to do this by using trigger not validation rule.

Comment: Why not use a validation rule?

Comment: Can you explain why it has to be a trigger as a validation rule is simpler to create, easier to deploy to other Orgs and easier to maintain?

Answer (score 2):

Try this - let me know if it works !

trigger LeadPreventInsertion on Lead(Before Insert){

```
  if(Trigger.isInsert){
     for (Lead objLead: Trigger.new){
          if(objLead.FirstName.contains('R') || objLead.LastName.contains('R')){
             objLead.FirstName.addError('Name should not contain-R- letter in it'); // prevent insert

         }
     }
  }
}
```